# How to customize gradient colors in tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have project which is written with react and tailwind. I want to set custom colors in tailwind configuration. But my gradient colors are not working

```
 primary: {
      100: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), #7367F0",
      200: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)), #7367F0",
      300: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)), #7367F0",
      400: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)), #7367F0",
      500: "#7367F0",
      600: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), #7367F0",
      700: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), #7367F0",
      800: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), #7367F0",
      900: "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), #7367F0",
    },
```

---

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #312d4b;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: black;
  outline: slategrey;
}

.bg-primary-700 {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)),
    #7367f0;
}

.bg-primary-600 {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    #7367f0;
}

.hover-bg-primary-600:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
    #7367f0;
}
```

Other colors working very well without any problem. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

bg-primary-XXX won't work since it will be transformed into background-color which won't work for a gradient
to do a gradient you need to define your color in variable.
For exemple :

```
primary: {
      100: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
      //...
},

whatever: {
      100: "#7367F0",
      //...
},
```

Once you defined your array you can use it like this :

```
<div class="bg-whatever-100 bg-gradient-to-r from-primary-100 to-primary-XXX ..."></div>
```

For more information you can refer to tailwind documentation :

- gradiant color : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops
- background color : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Comment: Perfect reply. But can I create example index.css and use my css code there such as background : linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), #7367F0; then add it tailwind config ? I have figure out how to add and use it on my page via tailwind. But I want to set this custom css classnames in my tailwind config. Example : primary {900 : "custom-css-classname"} . Do you know something about that ?

Comment: I seems that you try to use custom styles. 
You can found more about it in this documentation : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles

Comment: I have read it, problem is here that I can use custom styles but I can not set it to tailwind config. Example when I create custom style in  css such as .custom then add my background code to it. I can use this code everywhere on my pages, like className = "custom" but I can not use tailwind actions here such as dark:, hover:, active: and etc. I want to add my custom css to tailwind config then use it as a tailwind component. In this documentation there is nothing like that :)

Comment: Can you show your css file please ?

Comment: I have edited post and add my css file. Example I want to add bg-primary-700 to tailwind config colors like primary { 700 : 'bg-primary-700'} or something like that. Because otherwise I can not fully use tailwind actions on this class

Comment: Did you try to add all you css in a @layer component like this ? 
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-component-classes

Comment: Yes, I have tried it also. Same result can use pages but can not configure specific config